# Ruby display every element

Tags: ruby, csv-import

In the section of the code below I am trying to extract a column from a CSV which is stored in @record.main_id. I am splitting the code to gain every comma separated value and store it in the MySQL table table_val in the column id. 
I need every instance of main_id to get loaded into id but instead the repeated values are not getting loaded.
example 2,3,4,6,4,6,8.
I need every instance in sequence but instead values are getting loaded as 2,3,4,6,8.

```
def get_id
   @record.main_id.split(', ').map do |f|
    values = {
    id: f     
  }
  @att = Table_val.new(values)      

 end
```

Answer (score 0):

How about :

```
def get_id
   @record.main_id.split(', ').sort.uniq.map do |f|
    values = {
    id: f     
  }
  @att = Table_val.new(values)      

 end
```

Check the [document](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Array.html#method-i-uniq) to get more info about `uniq` and `sort`.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `@record.main_id` gives a string of coma sperated `ids` like:

```
"2,3,4,6,4,6,8"
# split(',') should give following array:
["2", "3", "4", "6", "4", "6", "8"]
#Now
["2", "3", "4", "6", "4", "6", "8"].map {|f| values = {id: f} }
#gives expected result:
[{:id=>"2"}, {:id=>"3"}, {:id=>"4"}, {:id=>"6"}, {:id=>"4"}, {:id=>"6"}, {:id=>"8"}]
```

So it successfully got all `ids` (with duplicates) and kept the sequence, isn't this the goal? perhaps values are getting messed up from the CSV or something, put this piece of code is fine.